# Delay Audio on Windows 10 by a second

Tags: audio

Is there a way to universally delay audio in Windows 10 (I have Realtek Hi-Definiton Audio) as an example.

I have 2 reasons why I want to accomplish this

1) My audio is playing a quarter of a second before the video plays (out of sync). This is consistent in youtube, vlc media player, windows media player, pretty much any video content... the mouth will move 1/4 second after the audio. The delay builds up overtime as well, about 5 minutes in it becomes unbearable.

2) Unrelated to #1 I want to scan the audio and edit it in near real time. Searching for certain sounds and also reading certain subtitles.

Comment: It sounds like there may be other issues that need addressing, and delaying all audio at the driver level is merely a band-aid for the real problem. Perhaps try updating all drivers related to multimedia.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner I agree with point #1 but #2 I still want to delay the audio for real-time processing reasons.

Comment: I don't know of a non-hacky way to do it. But essentially you could hook into audio playback functions in your audio drivers and add a sleep call. This would take a bit of reverse engineering. I've done similar things with frida before. You'd need to do some analysis to find which functions you want to hook into (the audio playback related ones), then use the frida API to add a sleep. It might work. https://www.frida.re/docs/frida-trace/